# How to change IFS function to switch in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula `=ifs(OR(A1="January",$A$1="March",$A$1="May"),$A10,OR($A$1="April",$A$1="June"),$B11,OR($A$1="February"),$C10)` I would like to use switch instead of IFS without repeating A1="":

so something like this `switch(A1=("January" or "March" or "May"), A10, ("April"or"June"),B10, ("February"),C10)`

I know its wrong. So A1 cell is Month name that user will enter A10 , B10, C10 are values to be shown according to criteria in the formula If I use Switch, I need to repeat lot of words as well: so I expect the formula will be like this: `switch(OR(A1="January",A1="March",A1="May"), A10, OR(A1"April",A1="June"),B10, "February",C10)`

Any thought how not to repeat the (A1="")? if the value equals to the criteria then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why it would be a problem to repeat the `A1 = ""` bit, but try these formulas:

```
=choose( 
  match(A1, { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June" }, 0), 
  A10, C10, A10, B10, A10, B10
)
```

or

```
=switch( 
  true, 
  regexmatch(A1, "January|March|May"), A10, 
  regexmatch(A1, "April|June"), B10, 
  regexmatch(A1, "February"), C10, 
  iferror(1/0) 
)
```